# How to use std::sort on a 2d matrix by first columns?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, lambda

How can I apply std::sort to the following data structure?

```
static unsigned Data[][3] = {
  {A1, b1, c1},
  {A2, B2, C2},
  ...};
```

The ordering should be performed comparing the the first column:

```
{A,B,C} < {X,Y,Z} <==> A<X.
```

This code is auto-generated for inclusion in another C++ codebase, and at generation time I don't have access to the numeric values of the 'A's, so I need to order it at run time.

I tried the following:

```
std::sort(std::begin(Data), std::end(Data), Comp);
```

With Comp defined either as:

```
const auto Comp = [](const unsigned (&a)[3], const unsigned (&b)[3]) { return (a[0] < b[0]); };
```

or as:

```
const auto Comp = [](const unsigned a[3], const unsigned b[3]) { return (a[0] < b[0]); };
```

Although both lambdas work for std::range_equal, the compiler (gcc 4.8) does not accept the use of this lambda for std::sort, reporting as follow:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5491:55:   
required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) 
[with _RAIter = unsigned int (*)[3]; _Compare =    
f(const llvm::MCInst&, const OperandVector&, llvm::SMLoc&)::__lambda1]’
....
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2162:11: 
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
__val = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__i);
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

PS: I don't want to use

```
std::vector<std::tuple<unsigned,unsigned,unsigned>>
```

instead of

```
unsigned[][3]
```

neither

```
std::map<unsigned,std::vector<std::pair<unsigned,unsigned>>>
```

as data structure (the latter would avoid std::sort and std::equal_range)

Comment: arrays are not move-assignable, so you can't sort an array of arrays with `std::sort`

Answer (score 1):

Raw arrays are not move assignable, which is a requirement for [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

> **Type requirements**
>   - The type of dereferenced `RandomIt` must meet the requirements of `MoveAssignable` and `MoveConstructible`.

In order to sort, you'll just need a container whose elements *are* `MoveAssignable`. Like `std::array`:

```
using Inner = std::array<unsigned, 3>;
std::array<Inner, 4> arr = {
    {5, 1, 2},
    {6, 2, 3},
    {2, 5, 10},
    {5, 0, 0}
};

std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [](const Inner& a, const Inner& b){
    return a[0] < b[0];
});

// now, arr is {2,5,10}, {5,1,2}, {5,0,0}, {6,2,3}
```